# In general, is it ethical to make a copy of work source code and take it home as reference?

Tags: copyright, source-code, ethics

Is it ethical to make a copy of my work's source code, for the sole purpose of my own reference? By reference, I mean as reference where I can refer to it about how I (and my teammates) implemented various design patterns, architecture, etc. It does not contain any trade secret, product, secret algorithm or anything like that.

Note that I wrote many parts of the source code, and also the added value from me studying the code will also indirectly benefit the company I am working on.

Comment: This is more a legal than ethical question. Besides, remote access can be an alternative.

Comment: Do you mean to use it as a "reference" for non-work activies?

Comment: It is ethical (IMO); though may or may not be legal depending on your contract and local laws; OTOH IME no one is interested looking at your code in the recruitment process

Comment: @dan1111 for my own study

Comment: @BalogPal - Not 'no one'. I've only had one interview in 20 years, but I did have one where they wanted to see source code. I'm unclear what they wanted out of it, but some companies do ask. Note that I did end up working at the place.

Comment: ok, make it 'only one' then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take code home but you don't tell at work and have to do it secretly it's unethical.

Comment: +1, that was my thought as well.  If you are asking here rather than just asking your boss, that is probably a good sign that at least you think it is unethical.

Comment: I don't think this is a good rule of thumb. You also don't tell at work and do it secretly if you're looking for a new job, but it's not unethical.

Comment: @LouisRhys Edited the answer to make it more specific to taking code home.

Answer (score 1):

I think keeping a code example reference library from job to job is a good idea. It should be better than Google. I would encourage it if I was a boss.

- tell your collegues about it and especially your boss
- don't hide it, but you don't have to have it open on the net either.
- ask about anything proprietary
- exclude sensitive data and project names

Instead of having very broad design examples, I normally have a few lines of code or blocks to reference. A Factory Pattern example maybe but how much code is it going to take to show how to do BDD? There shouldn't be a complete application here.